# Como remover ads Interstitial luego de comprar la version Premium?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

Este es mi codigo asi muestro el anuncio , lo que quiero es integrarle la opcion de compra y que al comprar remueva el anuncio Interstitial pero hasta ahora no se como hacerlo, agradezco la ayuda ya que me podria servir para proyectos futuros.

```
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.IntersitialABS));

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    interstitialAd.loadAd(request);

    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){

        public void onAdLoaded(){
            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            }
        }



    });
```

Comment: como determinas que ya tiene la versión Premium?

Comment: No sé cómo hacerlo , es la primera vez que lo implementare por eso estoy buscando ayuda porque es algo que nunca había hecho, lo he visto en aplicaciones y quiero implementarlo a mi aplicación.

Comment: La logica es cargar cada vez un anuncio hastes de mostrarlo, entonces simplemente antes de cargar verificas si es premium o no. Asi decides si cargar o no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el usuario realizó la compra puedes obtener un valor boolean (Ejemplo `versionPremium`) para determinar si el usuario inicializa o no el anuncio:

```
if(!versionPremium){ //Si no es versión Premium inicializa Anuncio.

    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.IntersitialLeyesABS));
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitialAd.loadAd(request);
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
        public void onAdLoaded(){
            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            }
        }
    });
   
 
}
```

De otro modo si tienes varios anuncios en tu aplicación lo común es realizar un método que entregue el estatus

```
public boolean isPremium(){
    ...
    ...
}
```

este método sería llamado antes de inicializar tu anuncio en cada Activity

```
if(!isPremium()){ //Si no es versión Premium inicializa Anuncio.

    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.IntersitialLeyesABS));
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitialAd.loadAd(request);
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
        public void onAdLoaded(){
            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            }
        }
    });
 
 
}
```

Comment: Tengo una duda tengo ese trozo de código en muchas activitys unas vez haga la compra dejarán de mostrarse en cada activity los Intersitial?

Comment: Lo que se realiza es un método en una clase en donde se obtenga el valor de la suscripción, este método lo usarías para validar en cada Activity muestre o no el anuncio! :)